# Parse varargs list of type Class

Tags: ios, variadic-functions

I am looking to parse out a list of args that are of type Class in iOS Objective-C. I am currently getting a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS whenever I try and parse the list. Here is the implementation to parse the list.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSArray (Args)

+ (NSArray *)arg_fromArgs:(id)clazz, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;

@end

#import "NSArray+Args.h"

@implementation NSArray (Args)

+ (NSArray *)arg_fromArgs:(id)clazz1, ... {
    NSMutableArray *arguments = [NSMutableArray new];

    id eachObject;
    va_list argumentList;
    if (clazz1)
    {
        [arguments addObject:clazz1];
        va_start(argumentList, clazz1);
        while ((eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id)))
        {
            [arguments addObject: eachObject];
        }
        va_end(argumentList);
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:arguments];
}

@end
```

The `while ((eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id)))` line is where I get the bad access. Here is how I call it:

```
NSArray *classes = [NSArray arg_fromArgs:[Class1 class], [Class2 class], [Class3 class], nil];
```

I have tried changing the id variable to Class but that still doesn't do anything. Any ideas on how I can achieve this (aside from passing an array of classes directly in my methods)?

NOTE: This crash only happens on physical devices. It works perfectly fine on the simulators.

Thanks in advance

EDIT

This is how I solved it based on newacct's suggestion. Is there a way to not have to pass the first Class?

```
+ (NSArray *)arg_fromClass:(Class)clazz andArgsList:(va_list)argumentList {
    NSMutableArray *arguments = [NSMutableArray new];
    [arguments addObject:clazz];

    id eachObject;
    while ((eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id)))
    {
        [arguments addObject: eachObject];
    }
    va_end(argumentList);

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:arguments];
}
```

How I'm calling it.

```
- (void)someMethod:(Class)clazz, ... {
    va_list argumentList;
    va_start(argumentList, clazz);
    NSArray *classesToSync = [NSArray arg_fromClass:clazz andArgsList:argumentList];

    NSLog(@"Syncing Classes: %@", classesToSync);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce a crash

Comment: @newacct Are you running this on a simulator? I forgot to mention that the crash only happens on a physical device.

Comment: Still can't reproduce it. Please provide a self-contained example program.

Comment: @newacct Sorry for the late response, please find sample here: https://github.com/DMCApps/SampleCrashVarArgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the sample app you have posted. There is nothing wrong with your `+[NSArray arg_fromClassArgs:]` method. It is a varargs method that expects a variable number of object-pointer arguments with a `nil` argument at the end.

The problem is that you call this method like this in your `+[ArgReceiver convertArgsToArray:]` method:

```
[NSArray arg_fromClassArgs:args]
```

You pass one argument, with no `nil` argument at the end.

And the way your `+[ArgReceiver convertArgsToArray:]` method is written (it itself is a varargs method, which takes a variable number of arguments, the first of which you name `args`) seems to indicate that you intended to "pass off" the variable arguments from that method to another varargs method. But that is impossible -- in C there is no standard way to have a varargs function pass off its arguments to another varargs function.

The only way would be to have a separate version of the `+[NSArray arg_fromClassArgs:]` method which takes a single `va_list` argument (maybe call it `+[NSArray arg_fromClassArgsVaList:]` or something), for other varargs method to call (and which `+[NSArray arg_fromClassArgs:]` itself can call, so you don't have duplicate code). You can see this in the C API, for example, `printf` has `vprintf`, etc., and in Cocoa, `-[NSString initWithFormat:]` has `-[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:]`

Comment: Ah makes sense, I'll give that a try when I get a chance and get back to this question. In the mean time, do you have any inclination as to why this works fine on the simulator but not on a physical device? I'm guessing it has to do with the difference in processors and how they each handle the instructions? The other thing I'm slightly confused about is that if you debug the code, it goes into the `[NSArray arg_fromClassArgs:]` and still loops 4 times just crashes on the nil termination (unless I'm missing something else here).

Comment: @DMCApps: It crashes for me on simulator too. Anyway, it's just undefined behavior and there's no point going into why. Trying to read more arguments than were passed will probably read into other parts of memory which may or may not happen to have valid pointers to objects.

Comment: I marked this correct, but there's one issue I'm unsure of how to solve. My va_list doesn't have the first item from the parameters passed. Am I doing something wrong. I updated the code with how I am resolving it now but is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @DMCApps: That's right. The `va_list` only contains the variable arguments, i.e. the ones under the `...`, after all the explicit parameters. Since your first argument is an explicit parameter, it is not included and is separate. The thing is, there must always be at least one explicit parameter before the `...`. For cases like `printf` and `stringWithFormat:`, they already have an explicit parameter beforehand (the format) so they don't have this problem.

Comment: @DMCApps:  In your case, you want all the parameters including the first to be part of your list, so your first parameter must be outside the `va_list`. Which is fine. I guess the best solution would be to have the second function take both an `id` parameter for the first argument and a `va_list` parameter for the rest.